# Schoen and Yau's proof of the higher dimensional positive mass theorem

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, geometric-analysis

In April 2017 Schoen and Yau posted on the arxiv their solution of the time-symmetric positive mass theorem in all dimensions, which has been a significant conjecture since the 70s. As of now, July 2020, it hasn't appeared in a journal. Is there any consensus in the geometric analysis community on the veracity of the proof?

https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05490

Comment: It appears to be a concensus that questions like this one, asking for validity of preprints, are considered off-topic for being too broad. See here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/942/30186

Comment: It seems like there is a precedent of this rule being broken for notable mathematicians on major conjectures - even in cases where, for what it's worth, the papers are (at least outwardly) "crackpot", which this is not

Comment: It is claimed to be done much earlier by Joachim Lohkamp https://cds.cern.ch/record/981383 (also unpublished by some reason).

Comment: My (maybe wrong) impression is that Lohkamp's proof is not widely understood, either positively or negatively

Comment: It was just published here https://dx.doi.org/10.4310/SDG.2019.v24.n1.a10

Comment: It is yet unsatisfactory to see that a major result (over decades) like this is placed in a typically not rigorously peer reviewed collection of invited addresses called "Surveys in Differential Geometry" edited in chief by one of the authors, namely by Yau, and published in a volume on the occasion of his 70's birthday.

Comment: It has been utilized in some papers that are already published and whose authors are not directly related to Schoen and Yau (former PhD students, postdocs...), see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05263

Comment: This paper seems to cite Lohkamp for the result.

Comment: There are certainly some papers citing SY's paper for this result, e.g. by Coley and Ellis, Sakovich and Sormani, and Borghini and Mazzieri. Anyway, Schoen and Yau's approach seems obviously cogent and credible, and and so maybe the best answer to this question would clarify if there are particular parts of their work that are particularly technically demanding (or even possibly unclear). It is disappointing that their paper, along with Lohkamp's, have been out for four years without any (to my knowledge) detailed expository accounts or commentary (whether positive or negative).

Comment: May be the validity of the proof is not established. However, it seems to me that the idea presented to solve the problem is bright; In particular, that of Lohkamp, which seems to be closely linked to that of D. Christodoulou in its proof of the formation of trapped surfaces (cf https://arxiv.org/pdf/0805.3880). From my point of view, the Lohkamp attack technique is full of a huge potential, especially for mathematical general relativity.